# Adding a small random error to a list of normal vectors

Tags: python, vector

I have a list of normalised vectors, ie:

```
[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0.5,-0.3,...]...]
```

In order to model an error, I would like to rotate each normal via some small random angle (and plane) - different for each normal.

While adding small random numbers to the x,y,z of each normal and then re-normalising would be one approach, this won't properly reflect the distribution I'm looking for.

Any ideas what the most efficient way of doing this is?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the linear transformation for rotating vectors?

Comment: If you have a function `rotate(v, theta)`, then you can apply whatever distribution you like by parameterizing theta as the random variable. `theta ~ U[0, 1]` for instance. Or `theta ~ N[0, 1]`.

Comment: Ouch Scott! Yes I probably asked this question too soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is the naive approach that I've just implemented, in case anyone comes across this question.

```
def rotate_vector_by_random_theta(vector, max_theta):
    theta_x = (2 * random.random() - 1) * max_theta
    theta_y = (2 * random.random() - 1) * max_theta
    theta_z = (2 * random.random() - 1) * max_theta

    rotation_matrix_x = [[1,0,0],
                        [0,math.cos(theta_x), -math.sin(theta_x)],
                        [0, math.sin(theta_x), math.cos(theta_x)]]

    rotation_matrix_y = [[math.cos(theta_y), 0, - math.sin(theta_y)],
                        [0, 1, 0],
                        [math.sin(theta_y), 0, math.cos(theta_y)]]

    rotation_matrix_z = [[math.cos(theta_z), math.sin(theta_z), 0],
                        [-math.sin(theta_z), math.cos(theta_z), 0],
                        [0,0,1]]

    vector = np.matmul(rotation_matrix_x, vector)
    vector = np.matmul(rotation_matrix_y, vector)
    vector = np.matmul(rotation_matrix_z, vector)

    return vector

list(map(lambda x: rotate_vector_by_random_theta(x,0.1), [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]) )
```